# Disable logger in class called by other class

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm facing a problem with schedule job logging.

I have a class called `A` here is a schedule job run every minute.

Inside `A` call to class `B` where I placed some logical method and have some log inside `B` and B also called by some other class that not `A`.

Is there anyway I can disable log in `B` that called from `A` but not the other with log4j?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether the method has been called from another class or not. You just declare a `Logger` variable in every class and modify their log level.

You can add below line into your log4j properties file

```
log4j.logger.<package.class> = OFF
```

or you can do it inside the code

```
Logger.getLogger("package.class").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Seem you missed something... I want disable the log when B called by A only. The other called B just show log as normal. I know `log4j.logger.<package.class> = OFF`

Comment: Sorry about that but your question was a bit unclear on that...I don't think there is such thing for log4j properties which means you have to handle the logging inside your logic using the second option in my answer. Depending on where the call comes from, you can alter the `Logger` variable log levels.

Comment: You pointed out a way for me. When write the question my knowledge wasn't enough to make it clear. Thanks and sorry about that.